# Article uses home page template. Not sure how to change to article template

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am new to Joomla so dont fully understand what's happening. I have an article that displays using the home page template/theme, whilst other articles display as content pages.

I have tried placing this article in different categories to no avail.

Would anyone know how I can have the article appear as a normal page?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you got a menu item associated with the article? What do you mean 'a normal page'?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can understand you have assigned the same layout to the specific page as the homepage.
  If you provide a screenshot or maybe some information is regards to the theme you are using i may be able to assist you